# I want data in descending order but i got incorrect output in php

Tags: php, html

I want data in descending order but i got incorrect output.

```php
<?php

$selxx = "select * from a_points where type='class' GROUP BY en_no DESC";
$exxx = $con->query($selxx);
$ai = 0;

while($fetp = $exxx->fetch_object())
{ 
    if($ai <= 4)
    {
        $ai++;  
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }

    $points = 0;
    $temp = $fetp->en_no;
    $selt = "select * from a_points where en_no='$temp'";
    $ext = $con->query($selt);

    while($fett = $ext->fetch_object())
    {
        $points = $points + $fett->points;
    }
?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $ai; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $fetp->en_no; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $fetp->st_name; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $points; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>
```

Result:

[image: result]

What I want:

1   150570116027    karan   97
2   160573116003    Ravi    70
3   15097116013     Krish   40
4   150570116002    Ishan   20

Comment: `$selxx="select * from a_points where type='class' ORDER BY en_no DESC"; $exxx=$con->query($selxx);` its orderby not groupby

Comment: Formatted code block. Fixed image link. Simplified language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See your code.

```
$selxx = "select * from a_points where type='class' GROUP BY en_no DESC";
```

You should use order by clause in the query. Your query will be like this.

```
$selxx = "select * from a_points where type='class' ORDER BY en_no DESC";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i still get error.

Now it prints only one student details not all four in descending order.!!

Comment: check your data in the table a_point for type ='class'. The data is case sensitive in oracle.